# Hello everyone, I need help to align a f-string print. Whenever I try, the result is never as expected

Tags: python, alignment, f-string

In the code below I'm trying to print the keys and values of a list
aligned, but I don't know why it doesn't work as expected!

```
for k, v in enumerate(time):
 print(f'{k : >5}', end=' ')
  for d in v.values():
   print(f' {str(d): <17}', end='')
  print()
```

The result on PyCharm is always the same as below:

```
 ----------------------------------------
 0  Ronaldo          [3, 3, 3]         9                
 1  Joe            [3, 2]            5                
 2  Renato           [3, 4, 2, 5, 6]   20               
 ----------------------------------------*
```

Comment: Have you tried checking PyCharm console's font? It may NOT be monospaced, which means everything blows up

Comment: You are padding your names to a maximum of 5 characters, but some of them are longer. You can pad them a constant amount  that you know to be greater than the longest name, or find the maximum length necessary in the code if you want a better solution.

Comment: Can you just force the column width with a formatting definition, e.g., 
    print('%-20s' % k)

Comment: I've tried to adjust the PyCharm console's font, but it didn't change the misalignment. Also made some changes to the code and, apparently, what messes the alignment is when the user has short names, for example Joe. Whenever I use his name the other parts of the code are pushed further left compared to the rest of the users.

Comment: # main code
print(f"{'CODE '}", end='')
for k in player.keys():
    print(f' {k :<15}', end=' ')
print()
print('-' * 47)
for i, v in enumerate(team):
    print(f' {i :>4}', end=' ')
    for data in v.values():
        print(f' {str(data): <17}', end=' ')
    print()

Comment: # Print
CODE  Name             Goals            Total           
-----------------------------------------------
    0  Renato             [3, 2, 4]          9                 
    1  Binga              [4, 3, 2, 5]       14                
    2  Gah                [1, 2]             3                 
    3  Joe               [4, 5]             9                 
    4  Breno              [3, 2, 4, 1]       10                
-----------------------------------------------